# Angularjs modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just started discovering Angular.js and did the *Shaping up with Angular* course from [codeschool](https://www.codeschool.com/). I though didn't understand fully one aspect: in the course you create multiple modules with `var app = angular.module('modulename',[...])`, you wrap them in a closure and you include all the `js` files in your `index.html`.

I am confused because the guy was using the same `var app` expression in all the files, which were included in the `index.html` like this:

```
 <script src='file1.js'></script>
 <script src='file2.js'></script>
```

and in `file1.js` you had:

```
  (function(){
      var app = angular.module('file1Module', []);
       ...
    })()
```

and in `file2.js` you had:

```
  (function(){
      var app = angular.module('file2Module', ['file1Module']);
       ...
    })()
```

So the `app` object's scope is inside the closure, right? So it doesn't pollute the global namespace and this is why you can name them as `app` without overwriting each other, even though they are included at the same level. But this `app` object is tied to `file X Module` through the `angular.module(...)` call? Or there is something else going on what I didn't notice?

Comment: The global variable here is `angular` itself.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. My question is how does angular relate to the different objects I define as modules?